# Buy Gnosis tokens with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, console, erc-20

How to participate to Gnosis pre-sale using geth javascript console?

In gnosis official blog is described how to do it using parity but there's no information on how to do it using geth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

start geth console

`$ geth --fast console`

in console :

`var gnosisAuctionABI = [{"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":""}],"constant":true,"name":"bids","payable":false,"outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":""}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"receiver"}],"constant":false,"name":"bid","payable":true,"outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amount"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"receiver"}],"constant":false,"name":"claimTokens","payable":false,"outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"type":"address","name":"sender"},{"indexed":false,"type":"uint256","name":"amount"}],"type":"event","name":"BidSubmission","anonymous":false}]`

`var gnosisAuction = eth.contract(gnosisAuctionABI).at("0x1d0dcc8d8bcafa8e8502beaeef6cbd49d3affcdc");`

`var myAccount = "{your account}".toLowerCase();
var amount = 0.1; /* ethers you want to spend */`

`personal.unlockAccount(myAccount);
gnosisAuction.bid(myAccount, {from: myAccount, value:web3.toWei(amount), gas: 150000});`