# Transfer GNO tokens using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, gnosis

I couldn't find any documentation on how to transfer GNO tokens using go-ethereum (geth). So here it is.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15470/buy-gnosis-tokens-with-geth

Comment: @RichardHorrocks it is not the same, that method worked only in crowdsale

Comment: Understood, but someone coming to this thread might also find that thread useful (as I did). Related, not duplicate :-)

Answer (score 4):

start geth console

`$ geth --fast console`

in console :

`var tokenContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"dutchAuction","type":"address"},{"name":"owners","type":"address[]"},{"name":"tokens","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]`

`var tokenContract = eth.contract(tokenContractABI).at("0x6810e776880c02933d47db1b9fc05908e5386b96");`

`var gnoAccount = "{your GNO account}".toLowerCase();
var amount = 0.1; /* GNO tokens you want to send */
var destination = "{address where to send}".toLowerCase();`

check balance

`tokenContract.balanceOf(gnoAccount);`

transfer tokens

`personal.unlockAccount(gnoAccount);
tokenContract.transfer(destination, web3.toWei(amount), {from: gnoAccount});`

Comment: is this a generic process for ERC20 tokens or is it only for GNO token?